# Split File while Preserving Groups of Lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, split

I have a text file that looks like

```
[begin]
line1a
line2a
[end]
[begin]
line1b
line2b
[end]
[begin]
line1c
line2c
[end]
```

Each group has the same number of lines (4 in this case, including the begin and end tags), and in one file I have many of these line groups.

I know the `split` command can split a file into N files while preserving lines, but I'd like to split this file into N files by groups of lines. So in this case, each output file should contain only complete groups of 4 lines. For example, to split into 2 files, the output would be

```
#file1
[begin]
line1a
line2a
[end]
[begin]
line1b
line2b
[end]

#file2
[begin]
line1c
line2c
[end]
```

Are there any Bash tools that can do this?

Comment: You should look for a regex solution (sed, awk ..)

Comment: Why aren't there 3 files each with one group? Why are the first two groups in one file?

Comment: @KamilCuk In the example, I wanted to split the larger file into 2 files only. If splitting into 3 files, then I agree that there should be 1 group per file.

Comment: Ach, so why isn't it like this: one group in the first file and two groups in the second file? Can't you just `split -l4` and then merge them? I think with `split -l4 -n2` will do what you want for the input specified.

Comment: @KamilCuk That seems reasonable for 3 groups, but the file might have thousands of groups. Then it becomes complicated to do the merging such that all resulting files have roughly the same number of groups

Comment: Is the number of lines in the file and number of lines in a group known in advance?

Comment: So how do you choose when the group goes to the next file?  Ex. 1000 groups, 777 files. Should the first file have 334 groups and the rest have one group per file? I am missing the part how to calculate how many groups end up in which files.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, the number of lines per group is fixed, and the number of groups in the file can be known. In the case of 1000 groups and and 777 files, I imagined the result being equivalent to split -n777 <file with 1000 lines>. Round robin would also be acceptable for my particular case.

Comment: So maybe do it like this: Replace all the newlines in each group by some character, ex. `[begin]!line1a!line2a![end]` is the first group with `!` as separator. Then run `split -n777`?

Comment: Using @KamilCuk's suggestion, I can do it with `sed`: Replace all newlines with a delimiter character, except on lines with the [end] tag, use `split` on the result, then `sed` again to replace the delimiters in each sub-file with newlines.

Comment: Still, why not just `split -l4 -n<number_of_files>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk `split -l4 -n<number_of_files>` gives me the error `split: cannot split in more than one way`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU split, csplit, ls, sed and parallel):

```
csplit -sz file '/^\[begin\]/' '{*}' # split each stanza into a separate file xx??
ls xx?? > k                          # make a list of the above files
split -n l/2 k                       # put each group of files in a new file x??
parallel -q sed -i 's/.*/cat & \&\& rm &/e' ::: x?? # replace x?? with contents
rm k                                 # clean up
```

Overview:

- Split the stanzas in `file` into individual files (`xx00, xx01, ....`).
- Make a list of those files (one per line) and put it in the file named `k`
- Split the list `k` into groups (in this case 2) new files named `xaa, xab, x..` which contain the names of the separate stanza files `xx00, xx01, xx..`
- For each `x??` file, replace the named stanza files `xx??` by their contents and then remove the original file.
- Remove the `k` file

Comment: This can probably be done faster using `parallel --pipepart --recstart '[begin]\n' --recend '[end]\n' ...`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, please try the following:

```
filename="file"         # assign to your filename
nol=12
gl=4
nof=2

l=$(( (((nol + nof - 1) / nof + gl - 1) / gl) * gl ))
# equals to ceil(ceil(nol / nof) / gl) * gl
digits=${#nof}          # length of suffix number

split -l "$l" -d -a "$digits" "$filename" "$filename"
```

I have followed the variable notations by Cyrus.